# Type 'Merge<FieldError, FieldErrorsImpl<DeepRequired<any>>> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'

Tags: reactjs

I have problem with variable error, in my Input.
I added to interface `error?: string`, why typeScript show me that this communicate?

```
Type 'Merge<FieldError, FieldErrorsImpl<DeepRequired<any>>> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
  Type 'Merge<FieldError, FieldErrorsImpl<DeepRequired<any>>>' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
Input.tsx(6, 3): The expected type comes from property 'error' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InputProps'
```

Bellow code:

Usage.tsx

```
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import * as yup from "yup";
import Form from "./Form";
import Input from "./Input";

// interface for form
interface EmailInterface {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

// validation
const EmailSchema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup
    .string()
    .email("Enter a valid email")
    .required("Email is required"),
  password: yup
    .string()
    .max(32, "Max password length is 32")
    .required("Password is required")
    .matches(
      /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})/,
      "Must Contain 8 Characters, One Uppercase, One Lowercase, One Number and One Special Case Character"
    ),
  secret: yup
    .string()
    .min(128, "Minimum legnth is 4")
    .max(32, "Max password length is 32")
    .required("Password is required"),
});

const Usage = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({ resolver: yupResolver(EmailSchema) });

  const onSubmit = (data: EmailInterface) => console.log(data);
  return (
    <Form
      buttonLabel="Change Email"
      register={register}
      handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      className="change-form"
    >
      <Input
        name="email"
        type="email"
        placeholder="Enter your email"
        error={errors.email?.message}
        autoFocus
      />
      <Input
        name="password"
        type="password"
        placeholder="Password"
        error={errors.password?.message}
      />

      <Input
        name="secret"
        type="secret"
        placeholder="secret"
        error={errors.secret?.message}
      />
    </Form>
  );
};

export default Usage;
```

Input.tsx

```
import { FC, InputHTMLAttributes } from "react";

interface InputProps extends InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
  name: string;
  label?: string;
  error?: string;
  register?: any;
  wrapperClass?: string;
  className?: string;
}

const Input: FC<InputProps> = ({
  register,
  name,
  error,
  label,
  wrapperClass,
  ...rest
}) => {
  return (
    <div className={wrapperClass}>
      {label && <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>}
      <input
        aria-invalid={error ? "true" : "false"}
        {...register(name)}
        {...rest}
      />
      {error && <span role="alert">{error}</span>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ? I recently came across the same error.

Comment: The same problem

Answer (score 11):

`helperText={errors.email?.message?.toString()}`

Set the error message in helper text to a string, this will solve the problem, it solved it for me, check the code below

```
<TextField
          placeholder='Email'
          label='Email'
          fullWidth
          {...register("email")}
          sx={{
            mt: 3,
          }}
          error={Boolean(errors["email"]?.message)}
          helperText={errors.email?.message?.toString()}
        />
```

Comment: This looks like a [MUI Textfield](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/). The question is about types on a custom input component. This answer does not add any value.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do something like this:

```
<input type="email" data-error={errors?.email?.message?.toString()} />
```

Comment: This is the right answer, though it could use some elaboration, which can be found here: https://github.com/orgs/react-hook-form/discussions/8915 .

Answer (score -2):

Use FieldError type from react-hook-form for error field in InputProps.

There's an example in the docs that you can find on this page: https://react-hook-form.com/ts

Comment: thanks for replying, but I still understand. 
When I put   error?: FieldError; I get message:
` Type 'FieldError' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
  Type 'FieldError' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactPortal': key, children, props`

Can you explain what I should todo, and what I should learn for future?
At the moment I set errors?:any, but it is hot fix.

Comment: I used the same feature to show error in my webApp here: https://github.com/radomir-radionov/MagicStore/blob/master/src/modules/ModalWindow/Modals/SignInModal/SignInModal.tsx, you can see it, and here:  https://react-hook-form.com/ts you can see a good template